# Связь "Кнопка и действие"

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю маленькую игрушку, и не могу никак определиться в ситуации:

Есть кнопка и объект который будет реагировать на нажатие кнопки (Движение платформы). Где лучше обрабатывать движение платформы, в скрипте кнопки, или в отдельном скрипте на платформе?

Если второй вариант, то это нужно постоянно проверять состояние кнопки?

Кто сталкивался, и как решали?)

Сам больше склоняюсь к первому, но интуиция подсказывает что будет не очень красивый код с костылями!(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт кнопки файрит ивенты по клику таргет-объекту (или нескольким).
Скрипт платформы реагирует на эти ивенты и двигает платформу.

Comment: Собственно так и сделал:  скрипт на кнопке задавал "что делать" таргет-объекту, а скрипт на объекте уже это делал )